# Asset Catalog images not displaying in Watch Simulator using Xcode 10?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, apple-watch, xcode10, watchos-5

My asset catalog images (.pdf images shared between iPhone and Watch app) are not displaying when running the Apple Watch Simulator using Xcode 10.  They do display on the Xcode 9 watch simulator as well as on devices running Watch OS5.  Is this an Xcode Bug?

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: it looks related in some way to resizing with preserve vector data enabled

Answer (score 0):

Apple has just confirmed that it is a bug of the Xcode 10 simulators and that this issue is not present in real devices.

It happens only with .pdf images when the preserve vector data option is enabled.